# What is the custom method for searching data in List<String> using CrudRepository?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, crud-repository

Lets say we have

```
class User{
 String userName;
 String userId;
 List<String> courses;
}
```

Inside repository I have

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,String>{
    List<User> findByUserNameIn(List<String> userNameList); // this works
    List<User> findByCoursesIn(String courseId); // doesn't work
}
```

What i want is to take **courseId** parameter and search that for match in **coursesList** and return **user list** who contains that **courseId**.

Comment: It seems like you need to define one-to-many relationship between User and Courses. Then you can search by course ID and get the user details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `List<String> courses` has a `@ElementCollection` relationship.

Usage of keywords are described here: [repository-query-keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)

In your case, you do not need to use the `In` keyword because that expects a Collection as a parameter.

So that should be:

```java
  List<User> findByCourses(String courseId)
```